# Косарь: сколько это и почему так называется?

Tags: этимология, жаргон

Косарь - это не только человек, косящий сено, но и на жаргоне - некое количество денег. Если честно, не помню, сколько - подобным жаргоном не пользуюсь.
Но, тем не менее, интересно разобраться в происхождении такого жаргона. Во-первых, сколько это, а во-вторых и главных, - откуда такое слово?
И картинка в тему:

[image]

Comment: 10 - чирик, червонец; 100 - косая, косарь; 1000 - штука, штукарь; 1000000 - лимон, миллион.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Косарь — это тысяча (рублей). Версию нашёл такую:

> > В период гиперинфляции 20-х годов XX века до введения золотого червонца ассигнацию в 1000 рублей называли "косая" или "косарь" (Купил 10 фунтов хлеба за две косых). Дело в том, что на первых ассигнациях раньше надпись шла по диагонали (косая). Поэтому бумажные ассигнации стали называть "косая", "косуха", "косуля", "косач", "коса", "косарь".

Answer (score 3):

Приведу в довесок цитату из "Очарованного странника" Лескова (1872—1873 года):

> А в руках она держит большой поднос, на котором по краям стоят много стаканов с шампанским вином, а посредине куча денег страшная. Только одного серебра нет, а то и золотом и ассигнации, и синие синицы, и серые утицы, и красные косачи, — только одних белых лебедей нет.
>
> ..................
>
> Да с этим враз руку за пазуху, вынул из пачки сторублевого лебедя, да и шаркнул его на поднос.

Из Википедии про ассигнации 1818-1849 годов:

В обиходе бумажные деньги часто именовались по расцветке.

Жёлтенькая  1 рубль
Зелёненькая 3 рубля
Синенькая (синица, синюха)  5 рублей
Красненькая 10 рублей
Беленькая   25 рублей
Радужная    100 рублей
Серенькая   200 рублей

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему "красные косачи" - у меня нет идеи. Возможно, со словом "косарь" они не имеют ничего общего.

Из данной информации я предполагаю, что ассигнации ассоциировались с птицами согласно цвету, но у [тетерева-косача](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%87) из красного только брови.